# Were printed manuals for HP PCL or GL ever published?

Tags: graphics, printer, books, hp

If one wants to learn about PostScript, it's possible to find copies of the "Red", "Green" and "Blue" books, which were published by Adobe.

Were similar manuals ever published about the HP graphics languages / data formats in printed book format?

It would be useful to find ISBN numbers if possible.

Comment: Do you mean reference books like the _PCL 5 Printer Language Technical Reference Manual_ (still available [here](https://developers.hp.com/system/files/PCL_5_Printer_Language_Technical_Reference_Manual.pdf)) and the _The HP-GL/2 and HP RTL Reference Guide_, or textbooks like, e.g. [this](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-663-14673-5)?

Comment: I really meant manuals, like the technical reference manual, but specifically as printed editions.

Comment: I've updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: In the 1980s, manuals were all in dead-tree format. I used various HP plotter manuals to write plotter drivers, and in one case, to demonstrate to Calcomp representatives that their HP-GL emulator did not meet the specification. Curiously, they weren't bothered if it behaved differently from an HP plotter but would only fix it if it conflicted with the HP manual. I don't have those manuals any more.

Comment: @JohnDallman yeah, before PDFs, CD-ROM and Internet ubiquity.

Comment: If I recall correctly PCL has HPGL as a subset.

Comment: TomH beat me to it. I have some of the exact same books.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were you doing that led to you having those books?

Comment: @PeterRussell  Somewhere around 1988, I contracted to write a printer driver for SunOS Unix to drive an HP A0 electrostatic plotter. Customer was plotting GIS maps overlaid with their assets (transformers, cables, overhead lines, switchgear etc) with a map background composed from builder's sketches, customer scanned maps, and Ordnance Survery vector and raster maps, all at different scales. I even wrote a C compression format which I unpacked at the plotter end in HP-GL. As soon as I got all that sorted, customers started demanding support for all kinds of other plotters.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My bookshelf says yes, they definitely were:

[image: photograph of PCL manuals on a shelf]

They don't appear to have ISBNs but there are HP part numbers:

- PCL 5 Printer Language Technical Reference Manual is 5961-0509 (1999 edition? [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Jho8oBteVzA), [Part 2](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/bpl13211.pdf))
- PCL 5 Developer's Guide is 5961-0546 ([1992 Edition](https://developers.hp.com/system/files/attachments/PCL_5_Developers_Guide.pdf))
- PCL 5 Comparison Guide is 5010-3998 ([2003 Edition](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/bpl13206.pdf))
- Printer Job Language Technical Reference Manual is 5010-3999 ([2003 Edition](https://developers.hp.com/system/files/PJL_Technical_Reference_Manual.pdf))
- PCL 5 Color Technical Reference Manual is 5961-0635 ([1999 Edition](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/bpl13212.pdf))

They are variously dated between 1992 and 1995 and I believe came from HP rather than any book store which likely explains the lack of ISBNs.

Comment: Wow, that's some good evidence! Thanks very much for sharing.

I had seen some evidence that there was a printed PCL 5 Technical Reference Manual, but everywhere seemed to use the same grainy photograph, that didn't really show the size of it, and could easily have been a stack of printouts.

Comment: That one is about two inches thick ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were you doing that led to you having those books?

Comment: That's actually the shelf above my desk at work and we were looking into doing PCL output at the time, many years ago now...

Comment: Plenty of people had these books. Before Google it was the easiest way to get PCL codes to do stuff.

Comment: I had 2 full sets at the office. We got them for free from a HP sales guy when we bought a batch of 20 Laserjet 4 printers in the 90's.  Came in very useful as a few years later I had to hand-craft various invoice layouts in PCL5 for an ERP system that only outputted plain ASCII. I just had the print-system prepend a header-page that was actually the entire layout in a PCL5 macro followed by the instruction to overlay that macro on every subsequent page of the print-job.

Comment: @Tonny - I think the "I just had (to)..." is quite modest of you.

Comment: @JonCuster I can't really say it was so special... This was a very common technique back in the day. The ability to insert a header-page was already an old standard on Unix systems in those days (going back as far as the 70's) and using that to insert an overlay macro was a rather obvious extension. In fact several ERP systems I used to work with back in the 90's employed this either as standard or with some add-on scripts.

Comment: @JonCuster did quite the same many times starting in the late 1980s. Except mostly using Kyocera printers and their PRESCRIBE language. The 1986 (or 87?) F1010 printer was a way better offering than any HP or NEC. More RAM, faster processing, lower print cost. Also that PRESCRIBE was a rather simple procedural language, so adaption was straight forward by first 'printing' a setup, followed rather simple formatted data records. Almost like punch card output :))

Comment: Ah, those were the days. I had a couple of customers where I got custom fonts made from logos and hand-coded PCL to download the logo font and print it where needed. Another I wrote my own PCL code for reports and had it running on both LaserJets and DeskJets (for color) over the network. Actually easier to send PCL directly than having to deal with Windows...

Answer (score 11):

Books? Manuals!

Both are simply the command language for specific HP products, which all had their detailed manuals printed and put in the box. Them becoming de facto standards is history at work :))

The Australian [HP-Museum website](https://www.hpmuseum.net/) is usually the best place to start a search about products and their manuals. They are not only exceptionally well stocked but also quite helpful (*1).

#### HP-GL

HP-GL started life as the command set for the 1977 HP-9872 plotter, thus its [manual/documentation](https://www.hpmuseum.net/exhibit.php?hwdoc=79) are the authoritative source to be looked at. After all, whoever needed to program one of them would have one, wouldn't he? (*2)

For the follow up GL/2 and RTL, made to cover non-plotter devices (aka graphic printers), a [description](https://www.hpmuseum.net/document.php?catfile=213) was published by HP.

#### HP-PCL

Same goes for [HP-PCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language) which is simply the command set developed for their first desktop Laser and Inkjet printers. Other than often colported (*3) PCL was not introduced in 1984 with the [ThinkJet](https://hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=300) and shortly followed by the [LaserJet](https://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=345),  but already a year before in 1983 with the first 'Bonsai' laser, the [2688A](https://www.hpmuseum.net/display_item.php?hw=343). Since the 2688A version was a superset of the ThinkJet instructions, it was in retrospect named PCL2.

Further development of PCL follows the development of HP printers and is literally just a write up of manufacturer-specific extensions introduced with new models - either to support new features (like colour) or to catch up with other manufacturers (think PCL6 to combat PostScript). The level to read about is defined by what device is to be programmed - making each model's manual the right source to look at.

Also, PCL6 is a completely different beast, defining a more abstract language to be compiled to what the printer understands - a bit like Windows GDI, which it does resemble in some detail. Its specs are [available on the HP website](https://developers.hp.com/hp-printer-command-languages-pcl/doc/hp-pcl6-pcl-xl).

---

*1 - Though it would be a good idea to know exactly what to ask for.

*2 - Those were simpler times. People got devices, read the books, programmed them...

*3 - including by Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you're right about the manuals for the early devices being the authoritative sources. I suppose these formats weren't really designed to be device independent languages from the beginning like PostScript was.

I've seen listings for the HP-GL/2 and RTL guide in print form online. I was lucky to pick up the PostScript books very cheaply, but the HP documentation seems to be a lot rarer, and more expensive.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer to this question, but I think yours is just as helpful and informative really.

Comment: Don't mind. Though, I thought it was about content and links to find them.  Taking a pic of one of my shelf  with HP manuals would have been less effort . They were all [dead tree versions long before](https://www.hpmuseum.net/exhibit.php?hwdoc=348).